# Check if external service is running

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to check if an external service is up and running or is hung. If the external process is hung, I have to kill it and restart it.

PROBLEM STATEMENT:
To check if the process is hung, I try to invoke it. If it is hung, I wont get any response and I would know that the service is hung.

The problem is when I try to invoke the process, and if it is struck, even the java thread would be hung, So I thought I could create a thread and invoke the process in that thread.

I will have a counter in parent thread and if the child thread does not return in some time, I would kill (call inturrupt()) on it.

But even, the parent thread hangs here.

I have a Class MyThreadHandler as follows:

```
public class MyThreadHandler {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThreadHandler myThreadHandler = new MyThreadHandler();
        myThreadHandler.handleThread();
    }

    public void handleThread() {
        System.out.println("STARTING LOOPER THREAD");
        boolean isRunning = false;
        int counter = 0;

        MyThreaad myThread = new MyThreaad();

        if (!isRunning) {
            myThread.start();
            System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            isRunning = true;
        }
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("while loop");
            counter++;
            if (!myThread.isAlive() || counter == 1000) {
                System.out.println("HUNG THREAD::: Killing thread");
                myThread.interrupt();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Thread class is as follows:

```
public class MyThreaad extends Thread{
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("STARTING LOOPER THREAD");
        MyLooper myLooper = new MyLooper();
        myLooper.loopIndefinite();
    };
}
```

And MyLooper:

```
public class MyLooper {

    public void loopIndefinite() {
        while (true){
            System.out.println("a");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) is what you might want. You can call `get` with a timeout. That's when the process is hung up.

Comment: This Article may help you with the [Interrupts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) (<-Link inside). How do you invoke the external Process?

Comment: My point is this is simple right, I create a thread that should execute something independant of the creator/parent thread.. Why use Whole threading framework if I am not going to do anything complex? This is simple scenario. I have to check for if a external process is hung, I cannot do It directly as my current thread itself would hang. I span a child thread and do the processing there. If the child thread id hung or does not return in sometime. I would call interrupt on it so it comes out of the hung state and then restart the external process.... Please somebody help...

Comment: So per link given by Fildor, I understand that only specific methods can be interrupted. I mean if the sleep() has been invoked, it can be interrupted. Not a thread which is hung as the resource it is waiting for is hung or unavailable.

Comment: interrupt() does nohing more than setting the interrupted boolean to true. If your thread does not check this value it will never stop. It's up to Runner thread to stop its process cleanly (interrupt() is not destroy())

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that both loops stay busy. In this situation, the thread scheduler may execute one loop for a long time, and the other (parent) appears hung.
The `MyLooper` loop can not be changed, I guess, because it simulates the hung process. The following could be done to make sure the parent thread gets some execution time:

```
public void handleThread() {
    System.out.println("STARTING LOOPER THREAD");
    boolean isRunning = false;
    int counter = 0;

    MyThreaad myThread = new MyThreaad();
    myThread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);  // <=== set priority

    if (!isRunning) {
        myThread.start();
        System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        isRunning = true;
    }
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);                  // <=== sleep
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("while loop");
        counter++;
        if (!myThread.isAlive() || counter == 1000) {
            System.out.println("HUNG THREAD::: Killing thread");
            myThread.interrupt();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I added 2 lines, one to set the thread priority of the "hanging thread" to a low value, such that the parent thread gets execution time even when the thread is busy. The second line is a `sleep`, this makes sure the parent thread doesn't take all the available execution time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't check for the interrupted state there's no chance that myThread.interrupt() will do what you want.

you have to add the following in the loopIndefinite method:

```
if(Thread.interrupted()) throw new InterruptedException();
```

Your loops are very aggressive for the CPU, you should not stress CPU like that. It's better to use ExecutorServices and Future as suggested by Fildor.